# How do I always can get browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest event when Mozilla Firefox is started by link?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Hello experts.

I can't figure it out myself. I’ve created an add-on:
1) manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Example",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "my-example@clear-code.com",
      "strict_min_version": "52.0"
    }
  }
}
```

2) background.js:

```
console.log("The first message ");

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  cancelReq,
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"] },
  ["blocking"]
);

function cancelReq(details) {
  console.log("Details: " + JSON.stringify(details));
  return { cancel: true };
}
```

Now, I click on the link, e.g 'http://www.google.com' when Firefox is closed. 1 out of 10 times on average Firefox is opened and the first URL is not fired.

I see the console:

```
16:02:44.750 Something... (It depends on the link page.)
...
16:02:45.491 The first message
```

How can I achieve to always get an event?

P.S. Maybe I do not understand the general mechanism of the browser? I would be grateful for theoretical references.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'persistent', Luke...   See [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background).